# JavaScript: ajaxSubmit error

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I have the following JS function triggered by a button:

```
function uploadPicture( ) {
    $("form#pictureUpload").ajaxSubmit({
        data: $("form#pictureform").serialize(),
        type: 'post',
        url: '?action=loadpicture',
        success: function(response) {
            $('#div-pictures').html(response);
        }
    });
```

}

This worked perfectly fine for several months. But it stopped working today in Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera - although it still works correctly in Internet Explorer.

Safari gives me the following mysterious error:

```
    Failed to load resource: cancelled       ?action=loadpicture
```

Chrome outputs almost the same (without `: cancelled`). Opera and Firefox show no error at all. The only additional information is that the errors above occur after the file upload is finished and although the server generates an HTML output as feedback which is ignored by the browsers.

Please let me know if you have any idea how to fix this. I've been running in circles for hours without even coming close to a solution - I simply see no errors in the code nor in the log files. Many thanks!

Comment: I don't know the answer, but a few ideas to investigate: 

-I don't think it's correct to specify ?parm=value when doing a POST request. Normally, when you do a GET request, all parameters you supply are appended to the URL in this fashion; when you POST, the values are submitted like form data. Try using a hidden input. I could be mistaken about this, maybe it's allowed even though it's not normal usage.

-It looks like you are posting back to the same page where this code is defined, not sure whether or not that is correct behavior?

-Are you using a different version of jQuery than before?

Comment: No jQuery version is the same. The only difference I'm aware of was a minor update of Apache and mod-php.

Comment: Is '?action=loadpicture' works as before? Have you tried to call this url synchronously?

Comment: ?action=loadpicture works perfectly fine if I call it directly via my browser. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It took me a while, but I finally figured it out. One of our admins added to the Apache configuration:

```
Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "DENY"
```

Which caused an issue on certain browser because of the iframe usage described at http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload. After changing it to the following everything is working again (no code changes!):

```
Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"
```

Anyway, the error message on Safari & Chrome are cryptic. The strange behaviour without any error message on the others browser is even worse.

Comment: Make sure to accept this when you can, should save someone else a headache later on :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm you shouldnt be using the query string in the URL because when you call serialize its going to get turn the data into a query strung try this:

```
$("form#pictureUpload").ajaxSubmit({
        data: 'action=loadpicture&'+$("form#pictureform").formSerialize(),
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response) {
            $('#div-pictures').html(response);
        }
    });
```